# QGIS, clip my vector data with a DEM raster

Tags: qgis, dem, vector, clip, polygonize

I know that I cannot simply clip vector data with raster data.

I'm working in QGIS and I have vector point data of earthquakes (XYZ), and I have it projected on top of my raster data (.tif). However, my point data goes way beyond my raster data boundaries which is unnecessary.

How can I clip out the vector point data that is beyond the boundaries of my DEM file?
They are 100% in the same CRS.  I have tried "polygonize" (raster to vector) but for some reason, it kept giving me errors saying that the file couldn't be created. I also tried vector>research tools>select by location, which didn't work either.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Processing Tool > Layer tools > Extract layer extent* that will create a polygon that covers the complete extension of your DEM (Extent in the image).

Then, using the *Processing Tool > Vector overlay > Intersection*, you can create a new layer that contains only the points that are inside your raster (Intersection in the image).

This is an example of the result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I'm new to all of this and don't know what all the geoprocessing tools do yet. You're a lifesaver